# ¿Cómo cargar una ficha o tab de bootstrap 3 después de enviar un formulario post con php?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Tengo un par de "fichas" o nav-tab, una se llaman "CatContable" y otra "Balanza", respectivamente,  donde en cada una le ingrese un formulario como el siguiente:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
```

Todo con sus respectivos campos, selectores y botones Submit.

El problema radica en que cuando envio el formulario de la segunda "Ficha",la pagina se recarga y muestra la primera ficha (CatContable), si doy clic en la segunda ficha (Balanza), veo que todo el form y las funciones en php se ejecutaron bien, pero yo quisiera que se muestre la ficha de donde envié el formulario.

investigando un poco, encontré un JQuery que creo que serviria para este fin, pero no logro aplicarlo correctamente con cada formulario para que llame su respectiva ficha

```
$(function () {
$('#Tabs a[href="#CatContable"]').tab('show')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**OJO**. Lo que estás intentando usar es JQuery, no Javascript (JS), el cual es un plugin de Javascript y el cual tendrías que implementar si no lo has hecho ya. Tendrías que poner al inicio de tu html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Por otro lado, podrías hacer referencia directamente al id CatContable.

```
$("#CatContable").tab('show')
```

Comment: ya lo corregi jejeje es que estoy incursionando en esto, son mis primeros meses...

Comment: @HectorLoera Prueba a poner directamente la segunda opción y me dices a ver si te funciona :)

Comment: funciona con el código que compartí pero después de enviar el formulario PHP como hacer que identifique y se quede en la ultima ficha seleccionada o de donde se envió el formulario.

Comment: @HectorLoera ¿Como estas enviado el formulario? Me refiero, después de llamar al php, como vuelves a la página?

Comment: con un boton tipo submit y el método post en PHP

Comment: @HectorLoera Me refiero, ¿es en el mismo momento de realizar el submit cuando se recarga la página? ¿O realizas alguna acción en el php para volverla a cargar?

Comment: al momento de ejecutar el submit envía el formulario, pero no hago ninguna otra acción para volver a cargar.